# Calculate the integral $\int\limits_{0}^{3}\frac{\sqrt{\arcsin \frac{x}{3}}}{\sqrt[4]{9-x^2}}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Calculate the integral$$\int\limits_{0}^{3}\frac{\sqrt{\arcsin \frac{x}{3}}}{\sqrt[4]{9-x^2}}dx$$

I was only able to get a grade, but it gives me nothing. I can't think of a way to solve this integral. You can't use numerical methods if they don't give you an approximately accurate answer through non elementary functions. I was able to get a numerical approximation on the computer, but how do I solve the integral analytically?

$$\int\limits_{0}^{3}\frac{\sqrt{\arcsin \frac{x}{3}}}{\sqrt[4]{9-x^2}}dx \approx \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \frac{h}{6} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\arcsin \frac{x_i}{3}}}{\sqrt[4]{9-x_i^2}} + 4\frac{\sqrt{\arcsin \frac{x_i + x_{i+1}}{6}}}{\sqrt[4]{9-(x_i + x_{i+1})^2}} + \frac{\sqrt{\arcsin \frac{x_{i+1}}{3}}}{\sqrt[4]{9-x_{i+1}^2}}\right)$$

where $h = (3-0)/n$, $x_i = 0 + i \cdot h$, and $n$ is the number of sub-sections into which the interval $[0, 3]$ is divided

Comment: Let $x=3\sin\theta$, you get $I=\sqrt3 \int_0^{\pi/2} \sqrt{\theta \cos\theta}~ d\theta$

Comment: @MathFail Is this integral solvable?

Comment: @MathFail how to solve for $\int\sqrt{x\cos x}\:\:dx$

Comment: Can't you calculate through hypergeometric series?

Comment: Substitute $x=3\sin^2\left(y^2\right)$ to rewrite the integral as$$\frac6{\sqrt[4]{9}}\int_0^{\sqrt{\tfrac\pi2}}y^2\sqrt{\cos\left(y^2\right)}\,dy$$Integrating by parts then gives a result in terms of a multiple of the [second lemniscate constant](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=second+lemniscate+constant) plus an integral of an elliptic integral. All that's left is to compute$$\int_0^{\sqrt{\tfrac\pi2}}E\left(\frac{y^2}2~\bigg\vert~2\right)\,dy ...$$

Comment: Under substitution $x = 3\sqrt{t}$ you get
$$
I = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\int_0^1 t^{-\frac12}(1-t)^{-\frac14}\sqrt{\arcsin(\sqrt{t})}\, \mathrm{d}t
$$
The first part of the integrand is [Beta-esque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), so if you can turn the arcsine part into some series you might be able to evaluate some things.

Comment: @Partim Where is this integral coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the fun of using my favored $1,400^+$ years ond approximation of the cosine function
$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\sqrt{t \cos (t)}\,dt \sim \int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \sqrt{t\,\frac{\pi ^2-4 t^2}{\pi^2+t ^2}}\,dt$$ There is an antiderivative
$$\int \sqrt{t\,\frac{\pi ^2-4 t^2}{\pi^2+t ^2}}\,dt=\frac{2}{3} t^{3/2}
   F_1\left(\frac{3}{4};-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2};\frac{7}{4};\frac{4 t^2}{\pi ^2},-\frac{t^2}{\pi ^2}\right)$$ where appears    the Appell hypergeometric function of two variables.

For the definite integral
$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2} \sqrt{t\,\frac{\pi ^2-4 t^2}{\pi^2+t ^2}}\,dt=\frac{\pi ^2 \,
    \Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)}{6\, \sqrt{2}\, \Gamma
   \left(\frac{9}{4}\right)}\,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4};\frac{9}{4};-\frac{1}{4}\right)$$ which is $0.907705$ to be compared to the "exact" $0.907288$ obtained by numerical integration.

This can be justified by the fact that
$$\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\left(\sqrt{t \cos (t)}-\sqrt{t\,\frac{ \pi ^2-4   t^2}{\pi ^2+t^2}}\right)^2\,dt=1.594\times 10^{-6}$$

Answer (score 1):

If we use, as @MathFail commented, $x=3\sin(t)$
$$I=\int_0^3 \frac{\sqrt{\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)}}{\sqrt[4]{9-x^2}}\,dx=\sqrt 3\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\sqrt{t \cos (t)}\,dt$$

Using series expansion
$$\sqrt{\cos (t)}=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{2^n\,(2n)!}\,t^{2n}$$ the coefficients $a_n$ being sequence $A008990$  in $OEIS$.

Integrating termwise does not make any problem. Concerning the convergence, using
$$b_n=a_n\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\frac{t^{2n+\frac 12}}{2^n\,(2n)!}\,dt=\frac{2^{-3 n-\frac{1}{2}} \pi ^{2 n+\frac{3}{2}}}{(4 n+3) (2n)!} \,a_n$$

Using
$$a_n\sim 2^{5 n-1} e^{-2 n} n^{2 n-1} \pi ^{\frac{1}{2}-2 n} $$ as proposed by  Vaclav Kotesovec in year $2016$
$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} \sim  \frac{2 n^{1-2 n} (n+1)^{2 n} (4 n+3)}{e^2 \left(8 n^2+18 n+7\right)}=1-\frac{5}{2 n}+\frac{31}{6 n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$